# Wordpress pagination query_post

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I've seen on some posts that the pagination with a query_post must be initiated by the argument 'paged'.

Unfortunatly, it doesn't work : the page 2 is still the same as the page 1

My code :

```
if ( have_posts() ) : 

     $args = array(
               'category_name' => 'interview',
               'post_type' => 'post',
               'posts_per_page' => 1,
               'paged' => ( get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1),
               );

    query_posts($args);

        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
            the_title();
        endwhile;

        previous_posts_link('Previous');
        next_posts_link('Next');

    wp_reset_query(); 
else :
endif;
```

My website : http://www.overso.me/

Any idea ?

Comment: You shouln't use query_posts() if this isn't the main loop. Try the same args on `new WP_Query($args)` instead.

Comment: @Andreas Krischer I tried and it doesn't work :/

Answer (score 0):

Ok I tried this : http://callmenick.com/post/custom-wordpress-loop-with-pagination
and it works.

I replacec the `query_post` by `WP_query`thanks to @Andreas Krischer